# How to tell Mathematica to use Real Only Mode

Tags: plotting

How do I tell Mathematica to use real only mode. For example if I want to graph $(x-1)^{1/3}$ for $-3<x<3$, I need to use Real Only mode to get the right graph.

Comment: What is the problem with `Plot[(x - 1)^(1/3), {x, -3, 3}]`?

Comment: @bel, this might be a good time to use `Surd[]`/`CubeRoot[]`...

Comment: @J.M. `Plot[{Surd[x - 1, 3]}, {x, -3, 3}]` ?

Comment: @bel, that or `Plot[CubeRoot[x - 1], {x, -3, 3}]`. I don't have version 9, but I'm guessing that's how it should now be done.

Comment: @J.M. I see. Somehow I wasn't able to understand the meaning of  _"I need to use Real Only mode"_